# Team foundation Server api move files

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, tfs

I want to move a tfs file from one location to another on the server.

The process would be:

Given a server and project name - recurse a subfolder of the project folder and copy files to another folder location.

I have looked at many different examples, some use tfscollection object some workspaces etc etc. Being new to the tfs api I am getting a little confused.

Could someone please provide some code sample for this (I am using vs 2010)?

The code I have so far is:

```
NetworkCredential tfsCredential = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
tfsCredential.Domain = "dsi";

TfsConfigurationServer server = new TfsConfigurationServer(new Uri("http://tfs.domain.com:8080/tfs"), tfsCredential);
server.Authenticate();
VersionControlServer vcserver = server.GetService(typeof(VersionControlServer)) as VersionControlServer;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the Workspace class for this type of work. If you have an existing workspace, you can get your Workspace instance from the VersionControlServer instance that you already had. If not, you need to create a new temporary workspace, then download the files you need to make changes to this temporary workspace by using one of the Get() methods of the Workspace class.

I'm not sure you want to move or to copy the files. To move the files, use one of the PendRename() methods of the Workspace class. I don't see a recursive flag for this method, so you'll probably have to do the recursion yourselves and PendRename() for the files you want to move. This will add the files to the list of pending changes.

To copy the files, you'll need to make local copies of the files in your workspace first, then use one of the PendAdd() methods to add the new files to the list of pending changes in your workspace.

Finally, you can get the list of pending changes by GetPendingChanges(), then perform a checkin using Checkin().

All of these methods are of the [Workspace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.client.workspace.aspx) class.

Comment: Well I know I said move, but thats not necessary. I would like to just copy the files from one TFS folder to another. So you are saying that in order to copy, I must first download the files locally, then PendAdd() them to the new locations and check them in?

Comment: Yes. Unless you want to branch the files then you can use VersionControlServer.CreateBranch to create a new branch with the existing files, but the copied files will not be in the same branch as the copying files.

Comment: you lose history copying between TFS projects like this? Or only the association with Work Items?

Comment: If you rename you don't lose history, if you make a new copy then yes, the newly added files will have a different history. Another option is to branch the files, which will also preserve history.